# htaccess error after wordpress multisite installation

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My wesbite yofnel.com is view able when my htaccess is like this

```
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

But if I remove

```
# END WordPress
```

It doesn't work anymore. And gives me this error

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@yofnel.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Please help, I'm frustrated on setting up my multisite.

This is the error I found on error logs.

```
[Tue May 14 11:36:38 2013] [alert] [client 67.159.36.27] /home/yofnel/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteEngine must be On or Off
```

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled in apache? If not, this is what will happen. Also, that is a comment, so it isn't the end wordpress line. It is something else in that file when you're saving it.

Comment: I believe that mod_rewrite is enabled on my server because I have another wordpress multisite on another cpanel account and it's working fine.

Comment: Nvm the htaccess is working now.

I checked on cpanel file manager and see that the uploaded htaccess file is somewhat not arranged properly.

I used ftp to edit the htaccess and I saw this on cpanel
RewriteEngine OnRewriteBase /RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]# add a trailing slash to /wp-adminRewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -dRewriteRule ^ - [L]RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]RewriteRule . index.php [L]

So I just edited it with the proper line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvm the htaccess is working now.

I checked on cpanel file manager and see that the uploaded htaccess file is somewhat not arranged properly.

I used ftp to edit the htaccess and I saw this on cpanel

```
RewriteEngine OnRewriteBase /RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]# add a trailing slash to /wp-adminRewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -dRewriteRule ^ - [L]RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

So I just edited it with the proper line breaks.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Your question got me to look at the file in CPanel (who uses web-based editors when they can edit locally?) and lo and behold, my newlines were in Windows format, not Unix format. Fortunately, Notepad++ is capable of converting newline format, so I'm going to do that first every time I upload a settings file to a Linux server in the future.

Answer (score 3):

1)Add the code snippet to wp-config.php what they displayed in the box after the multisite creation.

2)Update the htaccess with the given code snippet.

3) Remove the # symbol from the starting of 'LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so' in the httpd.conf in the apache server config file save the file, restart the wamp server